# combinations and permutations, how can I formulate it?

Tags: matrices, permutations, combinations

What mathematical formulation that can help me to generate all possible (N x N) matrices where the sum of all elements inside each matrix equal constant number M ?
Note that: M > N 
If it can be solved using combinations and permutations, how can I formulate it ?

Comment: I assume you're looking for nonnegative integer entries.With the requirements here there's no need to think of matrices. This is the number of partitions of $M$ into $N^2$ parts, allowing $0$'s. I don't think there's an easy way to count those. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: How can I calculate all possible partitions of M into N^2 elements ?

Comment: As I said in my comment, there is no easy way to do that. You can start at the wikipedia page to study the question. If $M$ isn't too large a brute force recursive computer program will do the job.

Comment: @EthanBolker:  if order matters, and it seems to here, we are looking for compositions.  The number of those is easy

Answer (score 1):

If the positions of the matrix are distinct you are looking for [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $M$ into $N^2$ pieces.  There are ${M+N^2-1 \choose N^2-1}$ of them.  The Wikipedia article derives this.

Comment: I didn't mean the numbers in the matrix had to be different, just that you care where the numbers go in the matrix.  For example, $\begin {pmatrix}1&2\\3&2 \end {pmatrix}$ is different from  $\begin {pmatrix}2&1\\3&2 \end {pmatrix}$